# How can i use 1 facthandle in 2 separate KieSession?

Tags: java, multithreading, drools

I'm currently working on a project using drools and it begins to contain a lot of rules. To make my project clearer, i would like to split them in separate KieSession because some rules are totally independant from others. For instance, i have 4 rules which only look at the knowledge base and print different things dependaing on the knowledge base situation. The idea would be to fire thoose rules in a separate thread running in parallel of the main one. The main one will modify the knowledge base and the second one will only look at it and print things.

I created 2 different KieSession arise from 2 different KieBase but I don't know how to insert an object in both sessions.. I tried:

```
Object obj = new Object();
kieSession1.insert(obj);
kieSession2.insert(obj);
```

But then when i create and start my two thread, modifying obj in one thread doesn't restart the second one.

I don't know where the problem is from, if you have any idea it would help me a lot!

Thanks

Comment: If they're running in parallel in separate threads you can't change stuff in one and have it available in the other. There's no synchronization mechanism for this.

Comment: If your second set is just printing things you probably want to be using a listener anyway.